# How to have the same order in a JSON Array as a JSON response?

Tags: java, json

I am receiving a JSON response such as

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "0": {
    "fname": "john",
    "lname":"doe"
  },
  "1": {
    "fname":"jane",
    "lname":"doe"
  }
}
```

When I get this JSONObject and try to put it into a JSON Array such that element 0 is status:succes, element 1 is fname: "john", lname: "doe" .. etc. The result is mixed up. The array is not in the same order as the JSON Response. How can I parse the JSON Response and each element as a JSON Object in the same order?

Comment: Why do you want things to be in the same order?

Comment: You don't get an array from that json response. Why don't you parse each value and put it in an array in the order you want?

Comment: JSON objects are decoded into hashmaps/hashes/dictionaries/etc (terminology depends on the language). There is no inherent key order, so there is no guarantee of the order that keys appear.

Comment: What you really want to get is: `["success", {"fname":"john", ...}, ...]`, so make the server send it this way. If you can't, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If your key is "0" "1" etc. try this:

```
 NSMutableArray *ar = @[].mutableCopy;
    NSDictionary *json = @{};//Data back
    [ar addObject:json[@"status"]];
    for (int i = 0; i < json.allKeys.count-1; i++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
       [ar addObject:json[key]];
    }
```

Comment: Could you help me out in JAVA please. I am assuming NSMutableArray is a ArrayList and NSDictionary is a HashMap or table?